# Show/display entries next/prev except entries with lightswitch field active

Tags: entries, lightswitch, previous-next

I have projects on my portfolio that link to each other. I'm currently using previous and next links.

This is what my code looks like

```
{# Set parameters for prev/next elements list #}
{% set params = craft.entries.section('portfolio') %}
{# Get the prev/next elements #}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}
```

And then I call it to display it in my code like so:

```
<div class="projectsNavigation">
    {% if prevEntry %}
    <div class="previousProject">
        <a href="{{ prevEntry.getUrl() }}">
            <span class="visibleText">Previous</span>
            <span class="projectTitle">{{ prevEntry.client }}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if nextEntry %}
    <div class="nextProject">
        <a href="{{ nextEntry.getUrl() }}">
            <span class="visibleText">Next Project</span>
            <span class="projectTitle">{{ nextEntry.client }}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

My goal today is to hide the previous entry button if the previous entry has the `comingSoon` lightswitch field ON.

Answer (score 1):

I got it by simply adding a condition where I was displaying my previous entry.

```
{% if prevEntry %}

    {% if prevEntry.comingSoon %}

        {# if comingSoon field is active, hide the link #}

    {% else %}

    <div class="previousProject">
        <a href="{{ prevEntry.getUrl() }}">
            <span class="visibleText">Previous</span>
            <span class="projectTitle">{{ prevEntry.client }}</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```